# Как в условиях MVVM узнать где стоит каретка в RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Как в условиях `MVVM` узнать где стоит каретка в `RichTextBox`?

Comment: Хм, а зачем вам? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @VladD, есть `RichTextBox` и есть список смайликов. При клике на какой-то смайлик он должен вставиться в то место где стоит каретка.

Comment: Ага, понял. Да, имеет смысл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите. Это не так просто, но вполне делаемо. Лучше всего работать не со смещениями, а с `TextPointer`. Кроме того, каретка может «расползаться», когда юзер выделяет текст.

Небольшая проблема состоит в том, что `Selection` не является `DependencyProperty`, поэтому привязаться к нему сложно. Но можно, конечно, потому что есть event `SelectionChanged`.

Итак, чтобы привязаться к `Selection`, создадим attached property — присоединённое свойство. Для того, чтобы ловить событие, можно использовать code behind, но я вынесу это в `Behavior` для красоты (можно без него и обойтись).

Для начала создаём пустой класс, в который положим attached property:

```
class RichTextBoxExt
{
    public static TextSelection GetCurrentSelection(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (TextSelection)obj.GetValue(CurrentSelectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCurrentSelection(DependencyObject obj, TextSelection value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CurrentSelectionProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentSelectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "CurrentSelection", typeof(TextSelection), typeof(RichTextBoxExt),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Теперь behavior, для него подключим из nuget пакет `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF`. После этого делаем так:

```
public class CaretWatchBehavior : Behavior<RichTextBox>
{   
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        // при присоединении...
        base.OnAttached();
        // подпишемся на SelectionChanged
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        // и прочитаем текущее значение Selection в attached property
        RichTextBoxExt.SetCurrentSelection(AssociatedObject, AssociatedObject.Selection);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        // при отсоединении отпишемся
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // при приходе события прочитаем текущее значение Selection в attached property
        RichTextBoxExt.SetCurrentSelection(AssociatedObject, AssociatedObject.Selection);
    }
}
```

Дальше подключим простую VM-ку:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    TextSelection selection;
    public TextSelection Selection
    {
        get { return selection; }
        set { selection = value; OnSelectionChange(); }
    }

    public int startOffset, endOffset;
    public int StartOffset
    {
        get { return startOffset; }
        set { startOffset = value; NotifyPropertyChange(); }
    }

    public int EndOffset
    {
        get { return endOffset; }
        set { endOffset = value; NotifyPropertyChange(); }
    }

    void OnSelectionChange()
    {
        // при изменении Selection пересчитаем офсеты из позиции
        // начала и конца каретки/выделения
        var begin = Selection.Start;
        StartOffset = begin.DocumentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(begin);
        var end = Selection.End;
        EndOffset = end.DocumentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(end);
    }

    void NotifyPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Ну и немного UI:

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
        Title="Тест" Height="250" Width="250">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartOffset, StringFormat=Start offset {0}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" — "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EndOffset, StringFormat=End offset {0}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <RichTextBox
            local:RichTextBoxExt.CurrentSelection="{Binding Selection, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:CaretWatchBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </RichTextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

В привязке пишем `Mode=OneWayToSource`, т. к. мы не можем установить `Selection` с нашим текущим кодом.

Comment: Разобрался, все работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Вот и хорошо. Заодно получился пример, как из не-dependency-property сделать таки dependency-property.